# Ajax call, see elements visualy but Javascript doesn't see them

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, jquery

I would really appreciate your help, as I been looking over and over and completely lost in what could go wrong.

I have an Ajax call to web service, and from this call I am building some HTML structure. Up to this point everything is good, the data get pulled and I can visually see the structure.

However as my code continues and I try to read those elements later for some more manipulations, JavaScript doesn't see them at all, and on element counts I am getting zero.

Some relevant code from the project.
This function that runs first and basically builds the needed HTML piece

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "HistoryEventsWebService.asmx/getEventsData",
                    data: event_types,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) { //on success                  
                        var results = result.d;

                        $('#insidediv_container').empty();

                        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                            var insidediv = '';
                            insidediv += '<div class="insidediv">';
                            insidediv += '<span class="month">' + results[i].month + '</span><span class="day">' + results[i].day + '</span><span class="year">' + results[i].year + '</span>';
                            insidediv += '<div class="header"><span>Jan 08, 2010 - event one</span> </div>';
                            insidediv += '<div class="contentdiv">' + results[i].event_desc + '</div>';
                            insidediv += '</div>';

                            $('#insidediv_container').append(insidediv);          
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
```

Right after this upper function is done, my code is continued to next function, and that's where I have my problem!

```
 var currentbox = 0;
            var current_box_old = 0;
            var box_size = ($('.insidediv').width() + 1).toString();
            var box_count = $('.container2 > div > div').length - 1;

            //console.log(box_count);
            var min_range = 0;

            setScale(); //making slider visual elements

            //slider code
            $("#slider").slider({
                min: min_range,
                max: box_count,
                value: 0,
                animate: true,
                //step: 1,
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    current_box_old = currentbox;
                    currentbox = ui.value;
                    if (currentbox > current_box_old)
                        $('#insidediv_container').animate({ "margin-left": "-=" + box_size + "px" }, "normal");
                    else
                        $('#insidediv_container').animate({ "margin-left": "+=" + box_size + "px" }, "normal");
                }
            });
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I hope results.length is always super short.  Appending items to the DOM in a for loop is exceptionally expensive.  Append up a string and then append the big string once at the end of your loop for more super happy fun time (jQuery performance).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I did not even know about this. Will make sure to look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this isn't working is that the whole of the code you want executed must be inside the ajax success method. Because the ajax post is asynchronous, the ajax method 'returns' almost instantly and flow immediately flows to your second block of code. However, because it got there so quickly, the ajax post hasn't received it's results yet, so the success method hasn't been called yet, which in turn means that the elements you're looking for have not yet been inserted into the DOM.

If these are the rough modular steps in what your code is doing:

```
$.ajax (A) -> http post (B) -> success (C) -> add elements to DOM (D)
|
v
update new DOM elements (E)
```

Then the actual flow of code is A, B, E, C, D and not A, B, C, D, E.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh I see, What would be my steps than to make sure that the second function get called only after the first one fully completed ?

Comment: Wrap it in a function and then call it at the end of your success function to your .ajax call.

Comment: I think the latest jQuery also lets you chain additional .success() callbacks to the initial ajax request: $.ajax(blah blah).success(function(){blah blah}).success(function(){blah blah});

Answer (score 0):

Apparently JQuery Ajax has function complete. I ended up wrapping my second piece of code into function and making call from complete.

Thanks everyone for the help.